# On table row with contenteditable on ENTER click call jQuery focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table in HTML that has contenteditable set to true.

Now when I want to save my changes I can click elsewhere (focusout) and it will save my changes.

I want "Enter" click to do the same function as focusout.

I tried this so far but it did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td.editable-col').on('focusout', function() {
    data = {};
    data['val'] = $(this).text();
    data['id'] = $(this).parent('tr').attr('data-row-id');
    data['index'] = $(this).attr('col-index');
      if($(this).attr('oldVal') === data['val'])
    return false;

    $.ajax({   

          type: "POST",  
          url: "server.php",  
          cache:false,  
          data: data,
          dataType: "json",       
          success: function(response)  
          {   
            //$("#loading").hide();
            if(response.status) {
              $("#msg").removeClass('alert-danger');
              $("#msg").addClass('alert-success').html(response.msg);
            } else {
              $("#msg").removeClass('alert-success');
              $("#msg").addClass('alert-danger').html(response.msg);
            }
          }   
        });
  });
});
```

// THIS IS WHERE ENTER KEY should call focusout

```
$('td.editable-col').on("keydown",function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;  // ie||others
    if(key == 13)  // if enter key is pressed
        $(this).blur();  // lose focus
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

fixed this issue